# - Show the set $A=\{(m,n)\in N\times N : m\leq n\}$ is countably infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- Show the set $A=\{(m,n)\in N\times N : m\leq n\}$ is countably infinite.

If $A$ is countable then we need to show that there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$, but how can I show $A$ is countably infinite?

Thanks...

Comment: I thought that  it was the otherway around. If A maps to the natural numbers then A is countably infinite.

Comment: Do you have some limited set of premises we can use since it seems like we could say something like: 1) Subsets of countable sets are countable; 2) $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite; 3) $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$... Guido A has the mapping to show that $A$ is infinite.

Comment: @KitterCatter your comment should become an answer! I was trying to avoid proving/stating that $\mathbb{N}^k$ was countable to keep this elementary, but I think it's easier/the same to prove that for $k = 2$ rather than invoking that countable unions of countables sets are countable...

Answer (score 3):

Note that $A$ can be written as

$$
A = \bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{(m,n) : m \leq n\}.
$$

That is, $A$ is the disjoint **countable** union of sets $F_n = \{(m,n) : m \leq n\}$. These are finite: for a fixed $n$, the set $F_n$ has $n$ elements, namely $(1,n) , (2,n) \dots, (n,n)$. Thus $A$ is a countable union of countable sets, which says that $A$ itself is countable.

To see that is is infinite, observe that the mapping $d : n \in \mathbb{N} \mapsto (n,n) \in A$ is injective, and so $A$ cannot have a finite amount of elements.

Comment: For $d$ is cauntable we also need to show $d$ surjective, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, here $d$ is a function. My point was that, since we had already proved that $A$ was countable, to conclude we had to see that it was infinite. Since $d$ is injective, and there are no injections of the form $\mathbb{N} \to F$ with $F$ a finite set, then $A$ has to be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in a couple of approaches:

### Quick Approach

If anything goes in terms of premises then we know a couple of things:

1. Subsets of countable sets are countable
2. $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable
3. $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$
4. $A$ is infinite, see Guido's answer.

### Bijective Approach

While this isn't necessary to show that $A$ is countably infinite, but there is a mapping between $N$ and $A$. Namely for some $(m,n) \in A, x\in\mathbb{N}$ then $(m,n) = (\lceil\frac{\sqrt{8 x+1}-1}{2}\rceil-x+1,\lceil\frac{\sqrt{8 x+1}-1}{2}\rceil+1)$ and of course the other way is $x=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+m$